# WordPress Pagination not working in Loop

Tags: wordpress, pagination

i have a function for pagination inside the Wordpress Loop. The pagination is OK, but the link returned looks like `?paged=2` (this page come out blank). But when i change from `?paged` to `?page` it works like a charm.

Am i missing something?

ps: i has change format to 'format' => '?paged=%#%' but not change...

```
function pagination() {
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your format line says `paged` with a 'd'. Try changing that to just `page`.  Likewise, make you `get_query_var` reference `page`, too.

Comment: i changed but continues ?paged

Comment: What does the code to get_pagenum_link look like? What does it return?

Comment: i solved this, i remove "base" it works like a charm